# When using 62.5% for CSS in rem units, what should my text-size-adjust property be?

Tags: html, css

My HTML tag looks like this:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

I am using `font-size:62.5%` as I am using `rem` units for font sizing, padding and margins etc.

```
body {
     font-size:16px;
     font-size:1.6rem
}
```

The `font-size:62.5%` is a *hack* so that `rem` units are easy to calculate. This [site](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem) informed me of this.

*Question*

Does this mean then, that to stop mobile devices englarging text, my `-text-size-adjust` property should be the same as my HTML font size of `62.5%`?

So:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 62.5%;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: 62.5%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 62.5%;
}
```

Or should I use `auto`?

I am confused.

Comment: Assuming you're appropriately sizing your text for mobile, you should just be able to set `-text-size-adjust` to `none` as you don't need the browser to handle this on your behalf at all.

Comment: Thanks @delinear. I did read online that you should avoid "at all costs" using: `none`. I am not saying you are wrong, I am just asking what you think about this?

Comment: Using `none` [used to cause issues with page zooming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust#Browser_compatibility) in older webkit-based browsers (Chrome and Safari), but this hasn't been an issue for a while. That's the only issue I'm aware of with `none`, could just be that your source websites for that info are a bit out of date?

Comment: @delinear right you are - thank you!